# Dojo Calendar Matrix VIew

Tags: javascript, dojo, calendar

I am new in dojo and in js, my question is how can add event to dojo calendar with on clicked method and add exist events by json format to Matrix calendar.

It is part of code but it can't add event and not show Matrix Calendar
but if close this line //store: new Observable(new Memory({data: someData})),
Matrix calendar displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Calendar.css" />
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src='unicorn/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

    <script>
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojox/calendar/Calendar"],
  function(parser, ready, Calendar){
    ready(function(){


require(["dojo/store/Observable", "dojo/store/Memory"], function(Observable, Memory){


 var someData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    summary: "Event 1",
    startTime: "2015-01-01T10:00",
    endTime: "2015-01-01T12:00"
  }
];

calendar = new Calendar({
  date: new Date(2015, 1, 1),
  decodeDate: function(s){
    return stamp.fromISOString(s);
  },
  encodeDate: function(d){
    return stamp.toISOString(d);
  },
  store: new Observable(new Memory({data: someData})),
  dateInterval: "day",
  style: "position:relative;width:500px;height:500px"
}, "someId");
   });           
   }
          )}
  );
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <style type="text/css">
  .dojoxCalendar{ font-size: 12px; font-family:Myriad,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,clean,sans-serif; }
</style>

<div id="someId" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you mean create an event like in the code example by CRTL+clic?

```
// Enable creation of event interactively by ctrl clicking grid.
        var createItem = function(view, d, e){
            var cal1 = ActiviteCB.get("checked");
            var cal2 = TacheCB.get("checked");
            // create item by maintaining control key
            if(!e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || (!cal1 && !cal2)){
                return null;
            }
        // create a new event
        var start, end;
        var colView = calendar.columnView;
        var cal = calendar.dateModule;

        if(view == colView){
            start = calendar.floorDate(d, "minute", colView.timeSlotDuration);
            end = cal.add(start, "minute", colView.timeSlotDuration); 
        }else{
            start = calendar.floorToDay(d);
            end = cal.add(start, "day", 1);
        }

        var item = {
            unid: '',
            summary: "New event " ,
            startTime: start,
            endTime: end,
            calendar: cal1 ? "Activite": "Tache",
            allDay: view.viewKind == "matrix",
            idclient: '',
            TypeAction:''
        };          
        return item;
    };

    calendar.set("createItemFunc", createItem);
```

Not sure it's want your asked...